# Display paragraph with different ids on a button click in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a single button on my HTML page and two paragraphs say id = 'para_1' and id = 'para_2'. I want to display content in para_1 on load the page and on every second click of the button and content in para_2 on every first click of the button.

I have the following code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript">
         function setVisibility(id) {
             if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer'){
                 document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
                 document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
              }else{
                 document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
                 document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
              }
         }

        </script>
        <input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer'    onclick="setVisibility('para_2');";> 

        <p id ="para_1"> display this is on load and second click</p>
        <p id ="para_2"> display this on first click </p>
        <br><br>
  </body>

</html>
```

what it is currently doing is loading both the paras on load and on the second click hiding para with id = 'para_2'.

I am very new to HTML and am really stuck on this part.
Any help will  be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the visibility of the second paragraph to `display:none` inline so the paragraph is hidden on page load and toggle the visibility of the two paragraphs using the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator, removing the need for the `id` parameter:

```
<p id="para_2" style="display:none">display this on first click</p>
```

```js
window.setVisibility = function() {
  var para1 = document.getElementById("para_1");
  var para2 = document.getElementById("para_2");

  para1.style.display = para1.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
  para2.style.display = para1.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility();">
<p id="para_1">display this is on load and second click</p>
<p id="para_2" style="display:none">display this on first click</p>
```

If you used jQuery you could achieve the same functionality by toggling the visibility of paragraphs when clicking the button:

```js
window.setVisibility = function() {
  var $para = $("p");
  $para.toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility();">
<p id="para_1">display this is on load and second click</p>
<p id="para_2" style="display:none">display this on first click</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but I also want the 'para_1' to be hidden on the first click and to be displayed only on load and every second click of the button. basically only one para to be displayed on any given time

Comment: @pku - I strongly urge people, _especially_ those "new to HTML", that they **should not** use inline styles like `style="display:none"` — instead, learn to use CSS in `<style>` blocks and, even better, keep style in a separate `.css` file.  Inline styles are a _nightmare_ for maintaining your site later.

Answer (score 0):

The argument that you pass to the `setVisibility(...)` function is always `para_2` which means that you're not changing the paragraph with id `para_1` in any way.

There is no need to pass any parameters to this function, just set one element to be visible and the other to be hidden in both the `if` and `else` blocks, here is an example:

```js
window.setVisibility = function() {
       if (document.getElementById('bt1').value == 'Hide Layer') {
         document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
         document.getElementById('para_1').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('para_2').style.display = 'inline';
       } else {
         document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
         document.getElementById('para_1').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById('para_2').style.display = 'none';
       }
}
setVisibility();
```

```html
<input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer'    onclick="setVisibility();">
<br><br>
<p id ="para_1"> display this is on load and second click</p>
<p id ="para_2"> display this on first click </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that uses JQuery to perform this functionality. It just checks to see if the 1st paragraph is visible, if it is it hides it and shows the 2nd, if not it does the opposite.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#para_2').hide();

  $('#swapBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($('#para_1').is(':visible')) {
      $('#para_2').show();
      $('#para_1').hide();
    } else {
      $('#para_2').hide();
      $('#para_1').show();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type=button name=type id='swapBtn' value='Show Layer'>

  <p id="para_1"> display this on load and second click</p>
  <p id="para_2"> display this on first click </p>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some bugs in your code. I have corrected them for you.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">   
function setVisibility(id)  {
    if (document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer') { 
        document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'; 
    }
    else { 
        document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; 
    } 
} 
</script> 
<input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('para_2')"> 
<p id ="para_1"> display this is on load and second click</p> 
<p id ="para_2" style='display:none'> display this on first click </p> 
<br><br> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The main bugs were:

1. para_2 was visible on the load of document because you didn't specify 'display:none' for it.
2. Use display:block instead of display:inline

Comment: "I fixed it for you" is not a useful answer because it does not explain what was wrong or _how_ you fixed it. _What_ were the bugs in the code? _How_ have you corrected them?